# Fill Dates based on Consecutive occurrences

Tags: r

```
ID     Date
1    1-1-2016
1    2-1-2016
1    3-1-2016
2    5-1-2016
3    6-1-2016
3    11-1-2016
3    12-1-2016
4    7-1-2016
5    9-1-2016
5    19-1-2016
5    20-1-2016
6    11-04-2016
6    12-04-2016
6    16-04-2016
6    04-08-2016
6    05-08-2016
6    06-08-2016
```

Expected Data Frame is based on consecutive dates pairwise

`1st_Date` is when he visited for first time
`2nd_Date` is the date after which he visited for 2 consecutive days
`3rd_Date` is the date after which he visited for 3 consecutive days

For e.g :
For `ID = 1` , He visited first time on `1-1-2016` and his 2 consecutive visits also began on the `1-1-2016` as well as his 3rd one .
Similarly For `ID = 2` , He only visited 1 time so rest will remain blank
For `ID = 3` , he visited 1st Time on `6-1-2016` but visited for 2 consecutive days starting on `11-1-2016`.

`NOTE : This has to be done till earliest 3rd Date only`

Expected Output

```
ID     1st_Date      2nd_Date      3rd_Date            
1      1-1-2016      1-1-2016      1-1-2016
2      5-1-2016         NA            NA
3      6-1-2016      11-1-2016        NA
4      7-1-2016         NA            NA
5      9-1-2016      19-1-2016        NA
6      11-04-2016    11-04-2016     04-08-2016
```

Comment: What if there are >1 sets of consecutive visits with the same number of days? E.g. Date = { 1,2,3,10,11,12 } ?

Comment: In this case , the oldest date will be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The first thing to do is to convert your `Date` to `as.Date` and `group_by` the IDs. We next create a few new variables. The first one, `new`, checks to see which dates are consecutive. `Date` is then updated to give NA for those consecutive dates. However, If not all the dates are consecutive, then we filter out the ones that were converted to NA. We then `fill` (replace NA with latest non-na date for each ID), remove unwanted columns and `spread`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = '%d-%m-%Y')) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(new = cumsum(c(1, diff.difftime(Date, units = 'days'))), 
         Date = replace(Date, c(0, diff(new)) == 1, NA), 
         new1 = sum(is.na(Date)), 
         new2 = seq(n())) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Date)|new1 != 1) %>% 
  fill(Date) %>%  
  select(-c(new, new1)) %>% 
  spread(new2, Date) %>%
  select(ID:`3`)

#  ID        `1`        `2`        `3`
#* <int>     <date>     <date>     <date>
#1     1 2016-01-01 2016-01-01 2016-01-01
#2     2 2016-01-05       <NA>       <NA>
#3     3 2016-01-06 2016-01-11       <NA>
#4     4 2016-01-07       <NA>       <NA>
#5     5 2016-01-09 2016-01-09 2016-01-09
```

**With your Updated Data set, It gives**

```
#     ID        `1`        `2`        `3`
#* <int>     <date>     <date>     <date>
#1     1 2016-01-01 2016-01-01 2016-01-01
#2     2 2016-01-05       <NA>       <NA>
#3     3 2016-01-06 2016-01-11       <NA>
#4     4 2016-01-07       <NA>       <NA>
#5     5 2016-01-09 2016-01-19       <NA>
```

**DATA USED**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L), Date = structure(c(1L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 
4L, 6L), .Label = c("1-1-2016", "11-1-2016", "12-1-2016", "19-1-2016", 
"2-1-2016", "20-1-2016", "3-1-2016", "5-1-2016", "6-1-2016", 
"7-1-2016", "9-1-2016"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: @numfig it's just the difference in days between your dates for each ID

Comment: ok this works , please put a summary of the logic you used here (or explanation) , would appreciate that :)

Comment: I have edited the question for more clearance, please see.

Comment: ok so in case if we have dates like Date  = (1,2,6,7,8,9) , i should get my 1st Date and 2nd Date as 1 and 3rd date as 7 as three consecutive vistis starts on 7, but in your solution above it returns 6 .

Comment: @numfig edited. I just added a `select` statement at the end

Comment: This just subsets the data down to 3 dates right? but as i stated above if there are non continuous dates and three consecutive visits have been made after non continuous dates then it should return the date from that particular set . See the ID == 6 above in the mentioned dataset. Anyways thanks for all the support .

Answer (score 0):

Use `reshape`. Code below assumes `z` is your data frame where `date` is a numeric date/time variable, ordered increasingly.

```
# a "set" variable represents a set of consecutive dates 
z$set <- unsplit(tapply(z$date, z$ID, function(x) cumsum(diff(c(x[1], x)) > 1)), z$ID)

# "first.date" represents the first date in the set (of consecutive dates)
z$first.date <- unsplit(lapply(split(z$date, z[, c("ID", "set")]), min), z[, c("ID", "set")])

# "occurence" is a consecutive occurence #
z$occurrence <- unsplit(lapply(split(seq(nrow(z)), z$ID), seq_along), z$ID)

reshape(z[, c("ID", "first.date", "occurrence")], direction = "wide",
    idvar = "ID", v.names = "first.date", timevar = "occurrence")
```

The result:

```
    ID first.date.1 first.date.2 first.date.3
  1  1   2016-01-01   2016-01-01   2016-01-01
  4  2   2016-01-05         <NA>         <NA>
  5  3   2016-01-06   2016-01-11   2016-01-11
  8  4   2016-01-07         <NA>         <NA>
  9  5   2016-01-09   2016-01-09   2016-01-09
```

Comment: Thanks , but this is just ordered date values ,Please see my expected result above.

Comment: This is very close just one exception is still there i have now modified the data i provided above , see ID 5 and you'll understand.

Comment: Then afterwards just need to remove duplicated dates from each row.

Comment: This will not work. If you remove duplicates then ID1 & ID5 will fail

Comment: I don't fully understand why repeated values are allowed  by "ID1" and not in other cases?

Comment: Because If you notice in ID1 all your dates are consecutive

Comment: I have edited the question for more clearance, please see.